# C++\Win32 Running application/thread in low priority mode?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I'm using CreateThread for my threads.

One thread is taking a lot of cpu %, I need to have that reduced.

Yes, I know I can just call Sleep(), but in this case its complicated to implement.

How do I set the thread to run in low priority or if not possible, then how do I run my application in low priority?

Comment: A `Sleep(0);` in the outermost loop is often enough to lower usage quite a bit. How hard could that be to implement?

Comment: 'One thread is taking a lot of cpu %, I need to have that reduced.'
Why?  If it's doing useful work, then why reduce it?  If it's not doing useful work, why is it running?

Comment: Thread.Sleep can be hard to implement if he's not in a loop, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SetThreadPriority function, for details search msdn

Comment: thanks, oddly that does not help with the CPU % even when set to idle.

Comment: Well, what is the thread doing?  If it's CPU-looping, it will take up a complete core unless other threads of a higher priority need that core.

Comment: Yes, you have a fundamental misunderstanding with how your CPU is allocated. Even an idle priority thread will consume 100% of your available (per-core, per-thread) CPU cycles if no other thread needs the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

SetThreadPriority will set the priority of individual threads. Alternatively, as you asked, you can use SetPriorityClass to change the base priority of the process. It is this base priority, combined with thread priorities, from which the actual thread priority is derived.